# How to configure KnpPaginatorBundle for Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4, knppaginator

I’m looking to implement  KnpPaginatorBundle into symfony4.

My issue here is that , in their documentation (meant for S3) they recommend using the following parameters i config.yml.

```
knp_paginator:
page_range: 5                       # number of links showed in the pagination menu (e.g: you have 10 pages, a page_range of 3, on the 5th page you'll see links to page 4, 5, 6)
default_options:                                 
    page_name: page                 # page query parameter name
    sort_field_name: sort           # sort field query parameter name
    sort_direction_name: direction  # sort direction query parameter name
    distinct: true                  # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    filter_field_name: filterField  # filter field query parameter name
    filter_value_name: filterValue  # filter value query parameter name
template:                                        
    pagination: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/sliding.html.twig'     # sliding pagination controls template                                    
    sortable: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/sortable_link.html.twig' # sort link template                                
    filtration: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/filtration.html.twig'  # filters template
```

I am not sure where to use these parameters as S4 does not come with a config.yml file.
I couldn’t find any documentation concerning KNP Bundle and S4. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the issue [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/issues/468) where the discuss about symfony4 problem, the configuration seems to be the same:

he places the config in "config/packages/paginator.yaml"

```
# config/packages/paginator.yaml
knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                       # number of links showed in the pagination menu (e.g: you have 10 pages, a page_range of 3, on the 5th page you'll see links to page 4, 5, 6)
    default_options:
        page_name: page                 # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort           # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction  # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                  # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
        filter_field_name: filterField  # filter field query parameter name
        filter_value_name: filterValue  # filter value query paameter name
    template:
        pagination: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/sliding.html.twig'     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/sortable_link.html.twig' # sort link template
        filtration: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/filtration.html.twig'  # filters template
```

Comment: So the place to put the config is "config/packages/paginator.yaml" where "paginator.yaml" could also be "knp_paginator.yaml" for clarity sake.